# Load and apply style thru command script

Tags: automation, styles, cytoscape

I automatically load a particular network when I start Cytoscape using a command script (-S flag).  I'd like to also load a style file (.xml file) and apply it to the network.  That is, the equivalent of:

- File->Import->Styles from File...
- Styles->Style Drop Down->Select new loaded style

Can this be done via any of the automation mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

The Cytoscape Automation wiki has instructions on how to find documentation on all the available commands:

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape-automation/wiki/Trying-Automation

The following commands should help you perform your task:

vizmap/load file
vizmap/apply